# How to make this figure using tikz in latex

Tags: latex, tikz

I use latex for various projects (teaching and research). I try to find a example to make a similar figure equal this [example of PSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0HgK.png) but not found.

[image]

Anyone have a idea how to make using tikz and LaTeX?

Comment: I found similar in http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

*tikz* alone is probably not the best package for the job. I would use *pgfplots* for which you can [find examples here](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/tag/3d/).